# Memory complexity of reassign in python

Tags: python, memory, complexity-theory

I'm wondering what is the memory complexity of reassigning a linear variable in python to a new linear type variable. For instance, consider a function with one list parameter, which converts it to set.

```
def func(list_var):
    list_var = set(list_var)
    return list_var
```

Is it O(n) memory complexity or O(1)?

Comment: Well the complexity of `func` is linear, you are converting a list to a set, so you need to iterate over all the elements of the list, hence `O(n)`

Comment: What do you mean by "linear type variable"? Is it an iterable?

Comment: @Fred yes I mean iterable

Comment: @DaniMesejo Sorry, I meant memory complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment itself isn't necessary; the following has exactly the same semantics from the view of the caller:

```
def func(list_var):
    return set(list_var)
```

The important part is the call to `set`, which has to allocate a data structure with `n` new references, one per element in `list_var`, so the space complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, understood it. But what if I initiate an empty set and then, in a loop pop the element from a list and add it to the set one by one. Would my memory complexity drop to O(1)?

Comment: It would depend on your underlying Python implementation. Removing an element from a list doesn't necessarily reclaim the memory previously used. Internally, the list would probably retain whatever memory had been allocated to it before your calls to `pop`; it would just be marked as available to use by future calls to (e.g.) `append`.

Comment: @BatyaGG At least in CPython, lists only store references to the elements while sets additionally store the hash values. So even if the list were able to immediately release each element's memory for the reference, it would decrease memory usage less than adding the element to the set would *increase* memory usage. So not O(1) overall.

Comment: @superbrain That would, though, represent only a constant factor increase in memory usage.

Comment: @chepner Hmm, not sure why you're saying that. I think we agree, but you make it sound like we don't. And `set(list_var)` is *also* "only" a constant factor increase. I can't make sense of your use of the word "only".